# Cant deserialize certian json property to c# property with Json.Net

Tags: c#, json.net

I am using this framework https://github.com/trydis/FIFA-Ultimate-Team-2014-Toolkit which makes some requests for me, however one method dont work anymore after a server update

```
Task<Item> GetItemAsync(long resourceId);
```

This tries to make a request with

```
internal class ItemRequest : FutRequestBase, IFutRequest<Item>
{
    private readonly long _baseId;

    public ItemRequest(long resourceId)
    {
        _baseId = resourceId.CalculateBaseId();
    }

    public async Task<Item> PerformRequestAsync()
    {
        AddUserAgent();
        AddAcceptHeader("*/*");
        AddReferrerHeader(Resources.BaseShowoff);
        AddAcceptEncodingHeader();
        AddAcceptLanguageHeader();
        var itemResponseMessage = await HttpClient
            .GetAsync(string.Format(Resources.Item, _baseId))
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
        var itemWrapper = await Deserialize<ItemWrapper>(itemResponseMessage);

        return itemWrapper.Item;
    }
}
```

this tries to Deserialize with

```
var itemWrapper = await Deserialize<ItemWrapper>(itemResponseMessage);
```

ItemWrapper.cs is

```
public class ItemWrapper
{
   public Item Item { get; set; }
}
```

And Item.cs is https://github.com/trydis/FIFA-Ultimate-Team-2014-Toolkit/blob/master/UltimateTeam.Toolkit/Models/Item.cs?source=cc

I added to Item.cs

```
public string Desc {get;set;}
```

The error I get is

> "Could not find member 'Desc' on object of type 'Item'. Path
>   'Item.Desc', line 1, position 16."

When it tries to deserialize this

> "{\"Item\":{\"Desc\":\"Staff Gold Rare\",\"Rating\":\"90\",\"Rare\":\"1\",\"Bronze\":\"24\",\"Silver\":\"24\",\"Gold\":\"28\",\"ItemType\":\"ContractStaff\"}}"

I cant understand why it wont map Desc to my Item.Desc property

Comment: From your post it's not clear if you added Desc to Item or ItemWrapper .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message it sounds like you added Desc to ItemWrapper and not Item. But your JSon has it as part of item. Move Desc to the Item C# class and it should work.

Comment: I added it to Item, not to ItemWrapper

Comment: Apparently Visual Studio would not change the dll even though I deleted the reference, added another one from Browse, it still used the one in my project folder (Not in the Bin, I cleaned and rebuilded) so when I overwrite the old dll file it worked